# Is there a clean way to create static inheritable generic constructors in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a 'Serializable' abstract class, the children of which I can create with a method call which takes a json object as the argument. I got it to work with the following code, but it results in a rather unwieldy solution.

My current code:

```
abstract class Serializable {
    public static deserialize<T>(jsonString: string, ctor: { new (): T}) {
        const newCtor = new ctor;
        const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        for (const propName of Object.keys(jsonObject)) {
            newCtor[propName] = jsonObject[propName]
        }
        return newCtor;
    }

    public static deserializeList<T>(jsonString: string, ctor: { new (): T}) {
        let newCtor = new ctor;
        const newArray = new Array<typeof newCtor>();
        const jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonString)['staff'];
        for (const jsonObject of jsonArray) {
            newCtor = new ctor;
            for (const propName of Object.keys(jsonObject)) {
                newCtor[propName] = jsonObject[propName]
            }
            newArray.push(newCtor);
        }
        return newArray;
    }
}

export class Employee extends Serializable {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

I can now create a new instance of Employee like this:

```
const testJson = '{"firstName": "Max", "lastName": "Mustermann"}';
const testEmployee = Employee.deserialize<Employee>(testJson, Employee);
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to do this:

```
const testJson = '{"firstName": "Max", "lastName": "Mustermann"}';
const testEmployee = Employee.deserialize(testJson);
```

I feel like there should be a way to not have to write 'Employee' three times in one line, but replacing anything with 'typeof this' has gotten me nowhere.
I realize this could be avoided by not making the constructor static, but instead having two lines:

```
const testJson = '{"firstName": "Max", "lastName": "Mustermann"}';
const testEmployee = new Employee();
testEmployee.deserialize(testJson);
```

But if there is any clean way to do this in one line, I would appreciate an example! I don't fully understand what the `ctor: { new (): T}` argument does, so my ignorance of a solution might stem from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can do that:

```
abstract class Serializable {
    public static deserialize<T>(this: { new(): T }, jsonString: string): T {
        const newCtor = new (this as any)();
        ...
    }
}

const testEmployee = Employee.deserialize2(testJson); // type of testEmployee is Employee
```

Notice that there's casting of `this` to `any`, that's needed because `Serializable` is abstract and so the compiler complains that it cannot be instantiated.
If you remove the abstract part then you can also remove this cast.

Also, there's no need to iterate over the properties like that, you can simply use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
public static deserialize<T>(this: { new (): T }, jsonString: string): T {
    return Object.assign(new (this as any)(), JSON.parse(jsonString));
}
```

Comment: That did exactly what I imagined. I'm a bit new to TS so I'll have to do some googling on this syntax, but the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: On which part(s) would you like to know more about? I can send you in the right direction.

Comment: I suppose my issue was finding a way to get the type of the child class from which the method is called. You supplied this through
this: { new (): T }
Does it automatically pass an instance of the object as the first parameter?

edit: Also props to reducing the entire function to a single line, if I could upvote this twice I would.

Comment: The compiler infers what `T` is based on the [definition of `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) and the fact that the function is executed on `Employee`

Answer (score 0):

It is about the type.

```
  abstract class Serializable {
    public static deserialize(jsonString: Employee) {
        const newCtor = new Employee();
        const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        for (const propName of Object.keys(jsonObject)) {
            newCtor[propName] = jsonObject[propName]
        }
        return newCtor;
    }

    public static deserializeList(jsonString: Employee) {
        let newCtor = new Employee();
        const newArray: Employee[] = [];
        const jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonString)['staff'];
        for (const jsonObject of jsonArray) {
            newCtor = new ctor;
            for (const propName of Object.keys(jsonObject)) {
                newCtor[propName] = jsonObject[propName]
            }
            newArray.push(newCtor);
        }
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

If you can't rewrite the abstract class, then you are forced to use it the way you already did.

Comment: That misses the point completely. The idea (as I understand it) is to be able to deserialize different classes, not just to `Employee`. Also, the `jsonString` is **not** of type Employee.

Comment: I agree. Anyway, I'm sure that he is not able to refactor the class so he is still forced to use it the way he already did.

Comment: There's actually a simple solution to what he's trying to do. Check my answer

Comment: Nitzan is right, it's easy to do in a non-generic way, but then I may as well implement it within the Employee class.